# SQL Server - measuring volumes of traffic and data

Tags: sql-server, traffic, measurement

We have developed a solution based around SQL Server 2008 and Reporting Services.

Now that we're deploying it and we're looking to put it in to customer SQL Server Clusters, they're of course asking a reasonable question:

**What sort of volumes of traffic and data will the app generate for the SQL server?**

I can work out the answers to various figures, based on the other figures the customer gives us (since the activity on the DB will depend on how much they use the system of course) - but what is the answer someone is expecting to this question? i.e. what units, what figures?

Queries per second?
Complexity of queries some how?
Some performance indicator that SQL Server can provide?
Data in kb/s or volumes per month?
How much data storage will be required on the server?

Or all the above?

Thanks in advance
Matt Peddlesden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take that question as either:

1. Traffic between the end-user and
   the SSRS server.  This can be
   significant if you're creating (for
   example) large multi-page XLS or PDF
   files.
2. TDS traffic between the DB Engine
   server and the SSRS server.  Again
   if you're pulling in large datasets
   then this can be significant,
   especially if the two boxes are on
   opposite ends of a WAN link.

In both cases it's network bandwidth usage.